# MySql Query adding number 1 to variable when used in query?

Tags: php, mysql, html

Hope you can help I have a simple query updating positions x and y based various user id etc. But I have a problem when I pass the variable to be updated (through ajax) to PHP, I get the variable fine but on placing it in a query a number 1 is added to the query end making the last id unusable (see example id 68 becomes 681).

Never seen this before, I am relatively new to sql tho, hope someone can shed some light on this?

```
$xupdate = $_POST['xupdate'];
$yupdate = $_POST['yupdate'];
$stickytext_id = $_POST['stickytextid'];
$user_id= $_POST['uid'];
$proj_id=$_POST['projid'];



echo $xupdate; //output 358
echo'<br>';
echo $yupdate; //output 203
echo'<br>';
echo $stickytext_id; //output 68
echo'<br>';
echo $proj_id; //output 7
echo'<br>';

$sql_update_stickyxy="UPDATE textsticky SET textsticky_x = $xupdate AND textsticky_y = $yupdate
                      WHERE textsticky_id = $stickytext_id";

echo $sql_update_stickyxy; //outputs UPDATE textsticky SET textsticky_x = 358 WHERE textsticky_id = 681 not 68?
```

Comment: Your code looks fine, as shown here. You forgot to include the user_id!!! Please close/end your $sql... with ";". Are you sure there is nor additional code that might add a "1". That could also be some kind of return TRUE; or an other concentanation you do later on $sql .= ...

Comment: Do you have another echo statement, or perhaps a `?>1` after this code?

Comment: You have an SQL injection holes in your code (as well as XSS) and possible syntax errors because you're not quoting your vars. (They'll bomb on non-numeric data).

Comment: Use `,` to separate fields to be updated. Using `AND` will not create a parsing error but your query and its result will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your echo'd output you obviously embezzled some of your code. As a first debugging measure you might use $_POST['stickytextid'] instead of $stickytext_id inside your query and see where it gets you.

Comment: probably something to do with my isset() checking - just moved code to fresh file and output is correct. I heard isset is not the best way of checking is $_POST is set. Any ideas from you guys how to better do it?